# Should a unique_lock be released after being unlocked if it won't be used again during its lifetime?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I am using a `std::mutex` to copy a `std::shared_ptr` at the beginning of a function.

```
// Lock the mutex
unique_lock<mutex> guard(d_mutex);

// Copy a shared_ptr
auto ptr = d_ptr;

// Unlock the mutex
guard.unlock();

// Operate with local ptr copy
```

During the operation, the guard remains associated with `d_mutex`.

My question is: is there any reason to `release()` the guard in addition to `unlock()`ing it?

Comment: No. By the way, there are _atomic_ operations for _std::shared_ptr_, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic.

Comment: @nosid: That's an answer, by the way :)

Comment: @nosid, thanks for the link -- I'll try that again. I seem to recall that last time I checked, gcc didn't support them properly. And yes, I'd accept that as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the member function `std::unique_lock::release` is to be able to transfer the ownership of the *lock* to some other place. It is similar to the member function `std::unique_ptr::release`, which transfers the ownership of the *pointer* (i.e. the responsibility to free the memory) to some other code.

That means: No, there is no need to *release* a `std::unique_lock` after it has been unlocked.

By the way: If you only have to protect concurrent accesses to a `std::shared_ptr`, then you should take a look at the *atomic operations* for `std::shared_ptr`:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic

These operations are already supported by Clang 3.5, although the implementation is not *lock free*. GCC 4.8 doesn't support these operations at all.

Comment: Isn't copying a `shared_ptr` thread-safe? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14482830/420683

Comment: @dyp: Yes, copying (i.e. reading) a `std::shared_ptr` is thread-safe, as long as no other thread writes to the same `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Ah ok. So you're protecting with the mutex or using atomic operations against a *write* to that particular `std::shared_ptr` object.