# Are the member function of shared_ptr , weak_ptr thread-safe?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am wondering the member function of `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr` are thread-safe or not?

For example:

Is the `weak_ptr::expired` an atomic operation?

Is `shared_ptr<CAT> spc = aother_shared_ptr_obj;` an atomic operation?

Thanks.

Comment: see e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482830/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety

Comment: I would assume that `expired` would be atomic... and *useless*. The fact that the `weak_ptr` is not expired when you call that function does not mean that it won't be expired by the time you try to do anything with it, even if it is immediately.

Comment: @David: Think the other direction: you call expired not because you want to  do something while the object is *alive*, but because you want to do something when the object is *dead*.