# Is shared_ptr swap thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr, swap

Here are some code snippets.

```
std::shared_ptr<int> global(new int(1)); 


void swapper(int x)
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int(x));  
    global.swap(sp); 
}
```

Suppose i wanted to call `swapper` in parallel threads. Would that be threadsafe?

I am aware of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482830/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety). It shows how assigning the pointer is not thread safe if i reassign a value to `global`.

My question is if the `swap` member function is in itself thread safe.

On the one hand the control block functions of shared_ptr are thread safe.
On the other hand i assume that i am swithing the pointers to the control blocks, so it should not be thread safe.

What is the connection there? Is `swap` thread safe?

Comment: Without addressing `swap`, this function should probably look like `global.reset(new int(x))`.

Comment: @Barry: Not if you want it to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, `swap` isn't thread safe, but there's another function that is:

```
atomic_store(&global, sp);
```

There's also `atomic_exchange` which returns the old value, if you need that.

Comment: [`atomic_exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_exchange)? But we're dealing with a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Barry: No, [`atomic_exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic).

Comment: That makes way more sense then!

Comment: [K13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13327906) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67077247) saying "Be aware that atomic_axchange is deprecated for std::shared_ptr since C++20: [http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2139r0.html#3.18](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2139r0.html#3.18)"