# Is shared_ptr destruction safe with multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-ptr

I have two classes similar to this:

```cpp
class Foo {
 public:
  void bar() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    m_data.push_back('x');
  }
 private:
  std::string m_data;
  std::mutex m_mutex;
};

class Pool {
 public:
   static std::shared_ptr<Foo> Create(int index) {
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
     if (m_pool.size() > 10) {
       m_pool.erase(m_pool.begin());
     }
     std::shared_ptr<Foo>& ptr = m_pool[index];
     if (!ptr) ptr.reset(new Foo);
     return ptr;
   }
 private:
   static std::mutex m_mutex;
   static std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Foo>> m_pool;
};
```

and several threads running this code:

```
void parallel_function(int index) {
  // several threads can get the same index
  std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo = Pool::Create(index);
  foo->bar();
}
```

[Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) says

> All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object. If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur; the shared_ptr overloads of atomic functions can be used to prevent the data race.

Two questions:

1. Since `Pool::Create` always returns copies of the `shared_ptr`, I assume that the copy and destruction of each `shared_ptr` is thread-safe, either if it happens in `m_pool.erase` or at the end of `parallel_function`. Is this correct?
2. I call `shared_ptr::operator->`, which is a const member function, and the function `Foo::bar` is thread-safe. Is there a data race here?

Comment: 1) "control block is thread-safe." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482830/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety 2) You should take a look at how race condition is defined

Comment: `operator->` is a const member: [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator*)

Comment: @KarlisOlte It looks like a typo given the quote from cpp-reference.

Comment: And, OP, 1st is also true. So basically your code is fine as long as Foo::bar being race-free stands true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To sum up my comments.

1. Yes, this is thread safe as you operate separate copies of `shared_ptr`s in different threads. Which is one of the few cases where passing copies of `shared_ptr`s is actually reasonable.
2. `operator->` is a [const member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%2A). So basically your code is fine as long as Foo::bar being race-free stands true (which it clearly is now).