# Sharing resources in Multi threaded programs C++ vs Java?

Tags: java, c++, c++11, concurrency

Hi I'm looking at the differences of how C++ and Java protect data corruption when sharing resources between multiple threads, in Java we can do many things like using the synchronized keyword:

```
public synchronized void inCounter
{
   this.counter++;
}
```

In C++ we can use a shared pointer:

```
shared_ptr<Song> sp7(nullptr);
```

My main question is the main differences I have to look at when using C++ and sharing resources and whether or not we can use synchronization the same as Java, coming from a Java background I am trying to learn more about C++.

Comment: Why would using a shared_ptr introduce protection? You need a lock like a mutex to control access

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14485302/4181011

Comment: @EdChum is right. you need to use [std::mutex::lock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock) to lock but not `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @TheApache, read Anthony Williams's "concurrency in action", chapter 7. there is function std::atomic::is_lock_free, shared_ptr may have atomic operations on some platforms

Comment: @jonezq But that means atomic operations on the *pointer,* not on its *pointee.*

Comment: @TheApache Load, store, exchange - what else needed for lock-free structure?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the differences is of limited value imho. You really need to ignore what Java does and study up on how to do multithreading in `C++`.

It is a long time since I used `Java` but I seem to remember its synchronization is fairly intuitive and high level. In `C++` you can use various techniques at different levels giving a great deal more flexibility and opportunity to be more efficient.

Here is a rough guide to how `C++` can be used to implement higher level synchronization, similar to that of (what I remember of) `Java`. But remember there is much more to multithreading and shared resources than this.

```
#include <mutex>

class MyClass
{
    std::recursive_mutex class_mtx; // class level synchronization

    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    std::mutex vec_mtx; // specific resource synchronization

public:

    void /* synchronized */ func_1()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(class_mtx);

        // everything here is class level synchronized

        // only one thread at a time here or in func_2 or in other
        // blocks locked to class_mtx
    }

    void /* synchronized */ func_2()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(class_mtx);

        // everything here is class level synchronized

        // only one thread at a time here or in func_1 or in other
        // blocks locked to class_mtx
    }

    void func_3()
    {
        /* synchronized(this) */
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(class_mtx);

            // everything here is class level synchronized
            // along with func_1 and func_2
        }

        // but not here
    }

    void func_4()
    {
        // do stuff

        /* sychronized(vec) */
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(vec_mtx);

            // only the vector is protected

            // vector is locked until end of this block
        }

        // vector is not locked here
    }

    void func_5()
    {
        static std::mutex mtx; // single function synchronization

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

        // this function is synchronized independent of other functions
    }
};
```