# std::locale causing errors with Helgrind

Tags: c++, locale, valgrind

While profiling my program with Helgrind, I noticed that I was getting a lot of errors similar to:

```
==8347== Possible data race during read of size 4 at 0x53C47A0 by thread #2
==8347== Locks held: none
==8347==    at 0x50E4E68: std::locale::locale() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==8347==    by 0x515B1DE: std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
```

and

```
==8347== This conflicts with a previous write of size 4 by thread #1
==8347== Locks held: 1, at address 0xFFEFFF638
==8347==    at 0x50E3115: std::locale::~locale() (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
```

So I was wondering, is this going to be a problem, and if so can I fix it? I know how to suppress errors with Valgrind, but I'm not sure if I should be worried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `std::locale` docs says :

> Internally, a locale object is implemented as-if it is a
>   reference-counted pointer to an array (indexed by [`std::locale::id`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/id)) of
>   reference-counted pointers to facets: copying a locale only copies one
>   pointer and increments several reference counts. To maintain the
>   standard C++ library thread safety guarantees (operations on different
>   objects are always thread-safe), both the locale reference count and
>   each facet reference count are updated in thread-safe manner, similar
>   to [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

So I would say you probably don't have much to worry about but in the other hand if you allocating (not just reading) pointer with reference count (like `shared_ptr`) in thread you'd better use lock to prevent wrong reallocation.

Here is a good explanation on it : [std::shared_ptr thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482830/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety)