# std::shared_ptr Thread Safe

Tags: c++, thread-safety, standards, shared-ptr

Is a shared pointer (std::shared_ptr) safe to use in a multi-threaded program?
I am not considering read/write accesses to the data owned by the shared pointer but rather the shared pointer itself.

I am aware that certain implementations (such as MSDN) do provide this extra guarantee; but I want to understand if this is guaranteed by the standard and as such is portable.

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

void function_to_run_thread(std::shared_ptr<int> x)
{
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
// Shared pointer goes out of scope.
// Is its destruction here guaranteed to happen only once?
// Or is this a "Data Race" situation that is UB?

int main()
{
    std::thread   threads[2];

    {
        // A new scope
        // So that the shared_ptr in this scope has the
        // potential to go out of scope before the threads have executed.
        // So leaving the shared_ptr in the scope of the threads only.
        std::shared_ptr<int>   data = std::make_shared<int>(5);

        // Create workers.
        threads[0] = std::thread(function_to_run_thread, data);
        threads[1] = std::thread(function_to_run_thread, data);
    }
    threads[0].join();
    threads[1].join();
}
```

Any links to sections in the standard most welcome.

I would be happy if people have reference to the major implementations so we could consider it portable to most normal developers.

- MSDN:   Check. Thread Safe.
- G++:     ?
- clang:   ?

I would consider those the major implementations but happy to consider others.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482830/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety it is from 2013

Comment: @ALX23z I saw that. But it is referring to s a specific implementation of shared_ptr (MSDN version). I am looking to understand if this is defined in the standard and thus portable.

Comment: [cppreference says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), "All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object. If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur; the shared_ptr overloads of atomic functions can be used to prevent the data race."

Comment: I’ve tried to give the backed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65615682/13782669)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have links to the standard. I did check this a long time ago, `std::shared_ptr` is thread-safe under certain conditions, which summarizes to: every thread should have its own copy.
As documented on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr):

> All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object. If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur.

So just like any other class in the standard, reading from the same instance from multiple threads is allowed. Writing to this instance from 1 thread is not.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread>   threads;

    {
        // A new scope
        // So that the shared_ptr in this scope has the
        // potential to go out of scope before the threads have executed.
        // So leaving the shared_ptr in the scope of the threads only.
        std::shared_ptr<int>   data = std::make_shared<int>(5);

        // Perfectly legal to read access the shared_ptr
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread([&data]{ std::cout << data.get() << '\n'; }));        
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread([&data]{ std::cout << data.get() << '\n'; }));

        // This line will result in a race condition as you now have read and write on the same instance
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread([&data]{ data = std::make_shared<int>(42); }));

        for (auto &thread : threads)
           thread.join();
    }
}
```

Once we are dealing with multiple copies of the shared_ptr, everything is fine:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread>   threads;

    {
        // A new scope
        // So that the shared_ptr in this scope has the
        // potential to go out of scope before the threads have executed.
        // So leaving the shared_ptr in the scope of the threads only.
        std::shared_ptr<int>   data = std::make_shared<int>(5);

        // Perfectly legal to read access the shared_ptr copy
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread([data]{ std::cout << data.get() << '\n'; }));        
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread([data]{ std::cout << data.get() << '\n'; }));

        // This line will no longer result in a race condition the other threads are using a copy
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread([&data]{ data = std::make_shared<int>(42); }));

        for (auto &thread : threads)
           thread.join();
    }
}
```

Also destruction of the shared_ptr will be fine, as every thread will call the destructor of the local shared_ptr and the last one will clean up the data. There are some atomic operations on the reference count to ensure this happens correctly.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread>   threads;

    {
        // A new scope
        // So that the shared_ptr in this scope has the
        // potential to go out of scope before the threads have executed.
        // So leaving the shared_ptr in the scope of the threads only.
        std::shared_ptr<int>   data = std::make_shared<int>(5);

        // Perfectly legal to read access the shared_ptr copy
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread([data]{ std::cout << data.get() << '\n'; }));        
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread([data]{ std::cout << data.get() << '\n'; }));

        // Sleep to ensure we have some delay
        threads.emplace_back(std::thread([data]{ std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{2}); }));
    }
    for (auto &thread : threads)
       thread.join();
}
```

As you already indicated, the access to the data in the shared_ptr ain't protected. So similar to the first case, if you would have 1 thread reading and 1 thread writing, you still have a problem. This can be solved with atomics or mutexes or by guaranteeing read-onlyness of the objects.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the [latest draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared.general#5):

> For purposes of determining the presence of a data race, member functions shall access and modify only the `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` objects themselves and not objects they refer to. Changes in `use_count()` do not reflect modifications that can introduce data races.

So, this is a lot to take in. The first sentence talks about member functions not accessing the pointee, i.e. that accessing the pointee is not thread-safe.

However, then there is the second sentence. Effectively, this forces any operation that would change `use_count()` (e.g. copy construction, assignment, destruction, calling `reset`) to be thread-safe - but only as far as they are affecting `use_count()`.

Which makes sense: Different threads copying the same `std::shared_ptr` (or destroying the same `std::shared_ptr`) must not cause a data race regarding ownership of the pointee. The internal value of `use_count()` must be synchronized.

I checked, and this exact wording was also present in [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), Section 20.7.2.2 Paragraph 4, so it should be safe to say that this requirement has been there since the introduction of `std::shared_ptr` in C++11 (and was not something introduced later on).

Answer (score 0):

shared_ptr (and also weak_ptr) utilizes atomic integer to keep use count, so sharing between threads is safe but of course, access to data still requires mutexes or any other synchronization.