# What mechanism ensures that std::shared_ptr control block is thread-safe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, shared-ptr, freertos

From articles like [std::shared_ptr thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482830/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety), I know that the control block of a std::shared_ptr is guaranteed to be thread-safe by the standard whilst the actual data pointed to is not inherently thread-safe (i.e., it is up to me as the user to make it so).

What I haven't been able to find in my research is an answer to **how** this guaranteed.  What I mean is, what mechanism **specifically** is used to ensure that the control block is thread safe (and thus an object is only deleted once)?

I ask because I am using the newlib-nano C++ library for embedded systems along with FreeRTOS.  These two are not inherently designed to work with each other.  Since I never wrote any code to ensure that the control block is thread safe (e.g., no code for a critical section or mutex), I can only assume that it may not actually be FreeRTOS thread-safe.

Comment: `libc++` and `libstdc++` are both open source versions of the standard library that you can look at to see how actual implementations do this.

Comment: It's up to the standard library implementer to decide how they implement that requirement, based on the tools available on the targeted platform or toolchain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't really much machinery required for this. For a rough sketch (not including all the requirements/features of the standard `std::shared_ptr`):

You only need to make sure that the reference counter is atomic, that it is incremented/decremented atomically and accessed with acquire/release semantics (actually some of the accesses can even be relaxed).

Then when the last instance of a shared pointer for a given control block is destroyed and it decremented the reference count to zero (this needs to be checked atomically with the decrement using e.g. `std::atomic::fetch_add`'s return value), the destructor knows that there is no other thread holding a reference to the control block anymore and it can simply destroy the managed object and clean up the control block.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC uses [InterlockedIncrement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-interlockedincrement) to increment the refcount, which is an atomic increment.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess from looking at the C++ library code is that the reference count is implemented as an atomic operation.  I am thinking that all the code eventually boils down to a set of built-in function implemented by the compiler for the specific architecture I am using (ARM).  Here a list of those built-ins provided by GCC: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html