# how to use atomic_store set shared_ptr to nullptr in multithread

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, shared-ptr

in [std::shared_ptr thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482830/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety), code like this is not thread safe:

```cpp
//In thread 1
shared_ptr<myClass> private = global;
...

//In thread 2
global = make_shared<myClass>();
```

and use atomic_store and atomic_load is thread safe

```cpp
//In thread 1
shared_ptr<myClass> private = atomic_load(&global);
...

//In thread 2
atomic_store(&global, make_shared<myClass>());
...
```

I try to use atomic_store set ptr to nullptr, but it is not allowed like this:

```cpp
std::atomic_store(&global, nullptr);
```

I want to know why can not set shared_ptr to null safely

Comment: [atomic_store](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_store) only works for objects that are atomic - `atomic<T>`.

Comment: You just need to replace `shared_ptr<myClass>` with `std::atomic<shared_ptr<myClass>>` (and you need C++20).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find I can use shared_ptr() instead nullptr, like this

```
shared_ptr<myClass> private = global;
std::atomic_store(&global, shared_ptr<myClass>());
```